# PHP Access Associative Array Value

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a key/value array as follows:

```
Array (
  [a] => - Item 1.1 \n - Item 1.2 \n - Item 1.3
  [b] => - Item 2.1 \n Item 2.2 \n - Item 2.3 \n - Item 2.4
  [c] => - Item 3.1 \n - Item 3.2
)
```

I have another array that I'm trying to set equal to the first. Basically, I get a POST request with a json encoded array, then I decode it, then I try to set key/value of one array equal to key/value of another.

Here's some code:

```
$requests = $this->get("request");
$notes_json = $requests->get("notes");
$notes = json_decode($notes_json, true);

$field_notes = array(
    "field_1" => $notes[a]
);
```

But it's not working, I get a server (500) error. I then tried to `echo $notes[g];` but I still get a (500) error. Can anyone tell my why PHP will not let me simply access a specific value of an array's key?

===== EDIT =====

`var_dump($notes)` results:

```
array(7) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(159) "- data 1.1
- data 1.2
- data 1.3
(note: extra data)
"
  ["b"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["c"]=>
  string(25) "- data 3.1
"
  ["d"]=>
  string(24) "- data 4.1
"
  ["e"]=>
  string(16) "- data 5.1
"
  ["f"]=>
  string(34) "- data 6.1
"
  ["g"]=>
  string(18) "(note: extra data)
"
}
```

Comment: show us the results from: `var_dump($notes);`

Comment: The first thing you should _always_ do when you get an error in a php script executed inside an http server environment: _take a look into the error log file_. That is where you can _read_ what the issue is instead of having to _guess_.

Comment: This is probably not what is causing your problem, but you should quote your array keys.

Comment: At the very least, it should be `$notes['a']` rather than `$notes[a]`... in PHP, strings (like your array key) should be quoted, otherwise PHP looks for a constant called `a` and issues a warning if it doesn't exist

Comment: **Is that a var_dump of `$notes` or what** Help us remove the guess work here

Comment: @Dagon, I updated question with `var_dump`. @arkascha, I looked at the logs, it just says error 500. It's a controller, so it doesn't provide a view to help me debug. @Don't Panic and @Mark Baker, I'll try that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters on my question, the solution was simple: *put quotes around the key*:

wrong: `echo $notes[g];`

right: `echo $notes['g'];`

Comment: should not cause that kind of error, would expect only a notice from php